# Can't create a new rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

when i use the terminal to create a new app i type Rails new book_app for example and create all the files but then stops and ask me to bundle install. This is what it looks in the terminal

```
Last login: Sat Jun 11 15:59:10 on console
Ahmeds-MacBook-Pro:~ AHmed$ cd desktop
Ahmeds-MacBook-Pro:desktop AHmed$ rails new book_app
      create  
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/mailers/.keep
      create  app/models/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/bundle
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  bin/setup
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/secrets.yml
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/assets.rb
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
         run  bundle install
```

It asks me to run bundle install. I have tried CTRL -C and bundle int manually but still nothing changed. Is there a way to generate that automatically because it used to be like that before when i create a new rails app?

Comment: It isn't asking you to run `bundle install`. It actually *running* `bundle install` and it takes some time.

Comment: i know but the problem is it takes a long time and won't finish. I left it for sometime and cam back and still running bundle.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be running bundle install at the end, but it probably takes a while. It looks like you mentioned it was taking too long. Try connecting to a better network.

Otherwise, if you run into a bundle install fail problem, make sure your versions of ruby and rails are compatible.